# Заголовок окна активного процесса

Tags: python, linux, bash, debian

Возможно ли узнать заголовок активного процесса с помощью Python или Bash ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: процесс не обязан вообще никакого окна иметь. Какой контекст у задачи? Какое окружение рабочего стола? Как "активный процесс" задан?

Comment: допустим, есть например плеер VLC как узнать имя окна, на 1 фото которое опубликовано в вопросе?
желательно без использования веб версии VLC

Comment: вы хотите узнать какое видео vlc проигрывает? у vlc есть API. Можно как из Питона так и баш http-запросы выполнять https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HTTP_requests/

Comment: @jts, если не ошибаюсь, то VLC умеет MPRISv2, т.е. никаких обращений через веб не нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим способом.
Спасибо @0andriy за наводку.

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
player = dbus.SessionBus().get_object('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc', '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')
metadata = player.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'Metadata', bus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
title_serial = str(metadata['xesam:url']).split("/")
duration = str(metadata['vlc:length'])
len_array = len(title_serial)
print title_serial[len_array-1]
print duration
```